# Unity how to load directory of files into a script and read them as text assets?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.io.file

I have a script attached to an object in Unity.  I want to load a folder of .vtk files into my project assets folder, attach that folder to the script on the object as I would attach any public variable to a script in the editor (by dragging and dropping it), and have my script read each .vtk file in the folder as separate TextAsset objects.  I would actually like each file to be an element of a TextAsset array, but that should be easy once I can get Unity to accept the folder of .vtk files as individual TextAsset objects.

I've tried declaring a public Directory and Path object to specify the folder, but I get the error that I "cannot declare a variable of static type 'Directory'".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for [Resources.LoadAll()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html).
The folder you're loading from needs to be in a folder named `Resources` inside your `Assets` folder for this function to work.

The function returns an array of objects, so you'll also need to cast them to TextAssets if you need that.

Example usage:

`TextAsset[] results = Array.ConvertAll(Resources.LoadAll("FolderName", typeof(TextAsset)), asset => (TextAsset)asset);`